# Does Python IDLE support sticky folder locations on File | Open?

Tags: python, file, python-idle

I frequently open Python scripts using IDLE's File | Open.

The default location at which the file browser opens is about 5 clicks away from where my Python scripts are stored.

I would like to know how to change that default location?

Also, does IDLE have any concept of sticky folders (i.e. open at the same folder you chose last) that can be turned on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I recall there are no such thing inside idle. But you probably could solve such inconvenience with some external tools.
Why don't just create simlinks to your desired locations in default idle dir? It'll be only 1 click away.

On win you could change working directory in IDLE label property's.
Not sure about *nix but probably there are something similar.

Also generally idle is just python script.
On win it's located at python PYTHONDIR/Lib/idlelib/idle.py:
So you can simply run it in desired location:

```
cd D:/my_favorite_scripts
python C:/Python27/Lib/idlelib/idle.py
```

Comment: Thanks Pill - I've gone with your first suggestion which is to create a shortcut to the folder where my scripts are located and then to cut/paste that shortcut to the folder the IDLE opens by default.